# Quote in which Rincewind talks about exams

Tags: discworld, terry-pratchett

In one of the Discworld books, there is a conversation in which Rincewind tries to justify his qualification as a wizard. He starts to say something like "I've passed dozens of exams" but catches the error and instead says something like "I've *sat* dozens of exams."

Can anyone help me to locate this quote? I think the last Discworld book I read was Men at Arms, and I have it in mind that the other individual in the conversation might have been Death (or Scrofula), but I'm not certain about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from *[Sourcery](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34499.Sourcery)*

> What? No! It says I’m a wizard, that’s what! Twenty years behind the
> staff, and proud of it! I’ve done my time, I have! **I’ve pas—I’ve sat
> dozens of exams!** If all the spells I’ve read were piled on top of one
> another, they’d…it’d…you’d have a lot of spells!”

He was speaking to Conina the Hairdresser, Cohen the Barbarian's daughter.

Comment: Thanks. Looking at the printing date in the edition I have, it's about 1/3 century since I read Sourcery. My memory wasn't too bad - just Death vs Conina was wrong. Easy mistake to make.